# How do packages work?

Tags: oracle11g, package

I've created a package with two procedures, one of which is to create a user. However when I execute the procedure although successful, I'm not seeing the user created..

```
    create or replace PACKAGE APPLICATIONPACKAGE AS 
    procedure CreateSingleUser( userName in VARCHAR2, rolename in VARCHAR2);
    PROCEDURE DeleteUser(userName in varchar2);
    END APPLICATIONPACKAGE;
    /
    create or replace PACKAGE BODY                                                                             
    APPLICATIONPACKAGE AS

     procedure CreateSingleUser( userName in VARCHAR2, rolename in VARCHAR2)
     AS
    dynamicsql  VARCHAR2 (2000);
    BEGIN

    BEGIN
     if rolename='APPADMIN' OR rolename='APPMODIFIER' or rolename='APPVIEWER'  
     THEN --limit user input to specific roles
 ----assign dynamic sql to a variable for excecution by excecute immediate
     dynamicsql :='CREATE USER ' || userName|| ' IDENTIFIED BY pass1234 DEFAULT  
      TABLESPACE USERS QUOTA 1M ON USERS PASSWORD EXPIRE';
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (dynamicsql);
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE dynamicsql;
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT ' || rolename || ' TO ' || userName || '';
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT CREATE SESSION TO ' || userName; 
     else
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Not a valid role...sorry role specified not given to    
      a user');
     END IF;
     END;
     END CreateSingleUser;
     PROCEDURE DeleteUser(userName in varchar2)
      AS
   deleteSql  VARCHAR2 (500);

   BEGIN
    deleteSql :='DROP USER ' || userName; -- assign drop user command to    
    variable delete sql
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (deleteSql);
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE deleteSql;  -- excecute the sql dynamically;
    END DeleteUser;
    ----- end procedure delete user-------

    END APPLICATIONPACKAGE;
```

Comment: I executed like this applicationpackage.createsingleuser('John','appadmin');

Comment: String comparison is case sensitive.  If you are passing a lower case string "appadmin" and comparing it against an upper case string "APPADMIN", that comparison will not be successful.  My guess is that your `if` statement evaluates to false, you don't have `dbms_output` enabled, and you're not seeing the `dbms_output.put_line` from your `else` (one reason that you should never rely on anyone ever seeing output written to `dbms_output`.